# How to add code from an R variable into a Quarto Code Block

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, quarto, reproducible-research

I have some code stored as a character.  I would like to dynamically add this code to a Quarto Code **Block** (Not a Code **Chunk** or [executable **Code Cell**](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html)).  I know I can add code into an executable code cell stored in an r variable, say, `MyCode` with the following lines of code:

````
```{r}
MyCode<-"2+3"
```

```{r}
#| eval: true
#| code: MyCode
#| echo: true

```
````

But is it possible to do this with a code block, and if so how?  I tried the following, but this did not seem to work:

````
```{r}
MyCode<-"2+3"
```

```{.r}
#| eval: true
#| code: !expr MyCode
#| echo: true

```
````

Comment: What about `eval(parse(text=MyCode))` in R code inside the chunk?

Comment: Does replacing `.r` with `r` in the second code chunk give the desired results? When I do it, the second code chunk returns a 5.